# How can I view the server performance using Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

The application I'm testing has two servers and I want to monitor and view the server performance. Please explain in simple layman language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy to implement. Please see the [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test), which will guide you step by step to measure the **server-performance**!!!

Hope, this will help you!!

Comment: Tried this already. But people tell me that this will give me the stats of my localhost not of the servers where the application resides.

Comment: You can monitor the server performance where the application resides. :) So, tell me what you have tried so far. I can help you. Thanks

Comment: That's what I've done thus far. Download JMeterPlugins-Standard-1.4.0.zip and JMeterPlugins-Extras-1.4.0.zip, unzipped them and placed the jar file in lib/ext. Downloaded server agent zip, unzipped it and ran in on my laptop which is windows via startAgent.bat. Then started Jmeter and uploaded my script, added the jp@gc- Perfmon Metrics Collector listener. Then I clicked on add row and localhost and 4444 came prefilled in Host/IP and Port sections respectively. I ran my script and graph shows results as well! Are these results of the servers or my localhost? I'm really confused. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's your localhost results. You can also monitor the server (where your tested application resides).

Comment: Please explain how can I monitor that! What needs to be done to monitor the servers?

Comment: To do this,
1. Install server-agent in your tested application server.
2. edit jmeter.properties like below:
remote_hosts=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx(tested server IP):4444
3. Now start your test from any machine and monitor the server performance using jp@gc- Perfmon Metrics Collector listener.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39842/discussion-between-mirk-and-rohan-kalia).

Comment: You can also check the other answer. I've explained how you can do it

Comment: @Rohan, Exactly!!! You can follow the other answer too. It seems perfect!! :)

Comment: Thanks Guys! That's the reason I spend so much time on the internet! I haven't implemented this yet, but I think I got the crux now!

Comment: You said the other answer is perfect as well!
But the other answer doesn't mention editing jmeter.properties! Is that needed as well? If yes, where and how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

If by server performance you mean server's health and resource utilization, then,

There is no built option for monitoring server health in JMeter. But, don't be disheartened, there is a plugin available for it. Name of the plugin is PerfMon Server Agent. You can download it from [here](http://jmeter-plugins.org/downloads/all). Documentation and tutorial for same are available [here](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMonAgent/).

To install the Server Agent **(ON YOUR SERVER)**:

1. Download Server Agent zip file.
2. Unzip file and place entire folder on your server (Make sure JRE is installed and configured on your server).
3. From within the Server Agent folder execute startAgent.bat(windows) or startAgent.sh(Linux). Keep this file running.

To setup and run your test to monitor server health you will need PerfMon Metric Collector listener in your JMeter instance. For this **(ON YOUR SYSTEM WHERE YOU WILL RUN JMETER)**,

1. Download StandardSet plugin from [Jmeter-Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/downloads/all/) site.
2. Extract the contents of zip file in your JMEter's root directory.
3. Start Jmeter and add your test plan to it.
4. Add PerfMon Metrics Collector listener to your test plan.
5. Add IP of your servers along with Port Number (default is 4444) and select the Metrics to collect.
6. Save your test plan and execute it.
7. You will see that your server health will be displayed in the chart in PerfMon Metrics Collector listener.

If by server performance you mean how much load your server can handle, then, I guess that is what JMeter actually does!